# Is Great Cannon essentially a JavaScript injection attack?

Tags: attacks, javascript, injection

I was reading an article on Great Cannon at Ars Technica (http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/04/meet-great-cannon-the-man-in-the-middle-weapon-china-used-on-github/) and it seems to me that this is basically a JavaScript injection attack which was then used to perform a DDoS.

It sounds like the media is spinning this into a "new type" of attack. Even the name "Great Cannon" seems to indicate that this is something special.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the [report](https://citizenlab.org/2015/04/chinas-great-cannon/) shows is not the uniqueness of the attack vector, but the systemization of the attack vector as a part of a national defence strategy.

> GC is an in-path system, capable of not only injecting traffic but
>   also directly suppressing traffic, acting as a full
>   “man-in-the-middle” for targeted flows.

...

> In addition, in contrast to the GFW, the GC only examines individual
>   packets in determining whether to take action, which avoids the
>   computational costs of TCP bytestream reassembly.  The GC also
>   maintains a flow cache of connections that it uses to ignore recent
>   connections it has deemed no longer requiring examination.

The issue, then, is the nationwide scope and reach for targeted, active response to websites with undesirable content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, essentially it is.

It is not what it is, but how it was achieved, which is what the hype is about.

It is a JavaScript injection attack on a global scale - both in terms of impact and in terms of the technological challenge to make it happen.